# Canbus, one host does not receive

Tags: microcontroller, can-bus

I have a small Canbus network containing three hosts: two Fujitsu MB90342-microcontrollers, which have been terminated, and one CAN-USB-converter to my laptop, with no termination. The three hosts are connected with a flatcable.
The problem is that one of the MB90342's doesn't receive from the other. It sends, receives when I send a message with my laptop, but doesn't receives the messages from the other microcontrollers.
The other MB90342 works just fine receives all messages. The used baudrate is 250K. 
Does someone have an idea what goes wrong?

Comment: How long is the bus?  Are both the micros running the same software?

Comment: No that was the problem. One did not allowed extended ID...